# How to Dynamically Change Method Receiver

Tags: go, mux

I recently learned you can do this in go:

```golang
type Env struct{}

func (e *Env) httpHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
   //...
}

func main() {
    // ...
    e := &Env{}
    router := mux.NewRouter()
    router.HandleFunc("/foo", e.httpHandler)
}
```

This is great for dependency injection since when I unit test I can simply call `httpHandler` with a mock env.

However, my question is... say you have:

```
method := e.httpHandler
```

Is there any way to dynamically change the value of the receiver `e` after `e.httpHandler` has already been stored into `method` with reflection or something? I can change the parameters passed into `method()` but it seems like the receiver value is locked in and the only way to change the receiver would be to do `e2.httpHandler`. This isn't possible in my case because I'm extracting `e.httpHandler` from the mux router and I just want to swap out `e` with a different receiver before calling `httpHandler`.

For more context I'm using `router.Walk()` to essentially do table driven tests where I iterate through every route, call the handler, check that the returned response is the correct shape, etc. However, some routes need slightly different database mocks than others and so it's not ideal to use a one-size-fits-all mock receiver for all routes in the router. I wanted to dynamically swap out the handler receiver with custom mock environments for select handlers.

Comment: It's not possible to swap, nor modify the receiver of a *method value* without direct access to the receiver.

Comment: You can group routes that require different dependencies. Like `Env1 -> router1` and `Env2 -> router2`.
When test `Env1`, Skip routes that should be tested in `Env2`. vice versa.

Comment: i think you should present your test code so we can understand where is it you are blocking.

Comment: Is the constraint that you are trying to use the same `mux.Router` for the entire suite of tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's my idea. What do you think?

```
type Env struct{
    db string // should be database, just example
}


func (e *Env) httpHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r * http.Request) {

}

// In case, create different router by different database.
func newRouter(db string) *mux.Router {
    e := &Env{
        db:db,
    }
    router := mux.NewRouter()
    router.HandleFunc("/foo", e.httpHandler)
    router.HandleFunc("/bar", e.httpHandler)
    return router
}

func TestByDatabaseA(t *testing.T)  {
    r := newRouter("foo")
    r.Walk(func(route *mux.Route, router *mux.Router, ancestors []*mux.Route) error {
        tpl, _ := route.GetPathTemplate()
        if !strings.HasPrefix(tpl,"/foo"){
            return nil
        }
        // run test
        return nil
    })
}

func TestByDatabaseB(t *testing.T)  {
    r := newRouter("bar")
    r.Walk(func(route *mux.Route, router *mux.Router, ancestors []*mux.Route) error {
        tpl, _ := route.GetPathTemplate()
        if !strings.HasPrefix(tpl,"/bar"){
            return nil
        }
        // run test
        return nil
    })
}
```

Comment: This is what I ended up going with because it seems like the only concurrent safe solution

Answer (score 1):

If you need a single router throughout the lifetime of your test suite - and since you cannot change the pointer receiver or re-register route handlers - you could try wrapping the `HandlerFunc` where you can change the handler function later:

```
type wrapperHandler struct {
    Fn http.HandlerFunc
}

func (wh *wrapperHandler) HandlerFunc() http.HandlerFunc {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        wh.Fn.ServeHTTP(w, r) // can change `Fn` later
    }
}
```

to use:

```
// setup
router := mux.NewRouter()
wh := wrapperHandler{} // fill in wh.Fn later
router.HandleFunc("/foo", wh.HandlerFunc())

e := Env{ /*db1*/ }
wh.Fn = e.httpHandler
runTest(router)

e = Env{ /*db2*/ }
wh.Fn = e.httpHandler
runTest(router)
```